# ASP.NET: Custom Server Control Click Events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, click

I'm developing a custom server control that all the html it's generated within the RenderContents, i have a list of custom objects, and for each one i draw a div, with the object info, and with two buttons on the top (one for remove the object from the list, and other to open an editor). 
After getting the design right, now i'm trying to attach the events, but i don't see how to do that.

For testing purposes i created an generic function:

```
protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Yeahhhhh!");
    }
```

I can't do something like this:

```
htmlWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, "OnClick");
```

So what's the solution? 
Create a button in the class, instantiate OnInit, in the render, call the Button.Render();

Thanks

***EDIT:***

Code that renderes the button inside the RenderContents

```
 //...
 htmlWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, "btSave");
 htmlWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, "btSave");
 htmlWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, "Save");
 htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);
 htmlWriter.Write("Save");
 htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();
 //...
```

Other approach, declaring the button, instantiate in onInit and render the button in the render:

```
//Private var
private Button bt1;

//OnInit
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    bt1 = new Button();
    bt1.ID = "btSave";     
    bt1.Text = "Save";
    bt1.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Pixel);
    bt1.Height = new Unit(30, UnitType.Pixel);
    bt1.Click += new EventHandler(Bt1_Click);
//...



protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter)
{
    //Other code
    bt1.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
//...
```

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of info to give a useful answer. But as I see it now you are adding a javascript `onClick`, not a aspnet one since you writing it as a string to the button. If you are creating dynamic controls you need to assign am event from code behind.

Comment: The onClick, was for testing purposes, doesnt work...
The code is a little long and complex, div, tables, spans. 
The real question is, how can i intercept in my code the button click, and if have a dropdownlist, enable the autopostback and handle the event?
Thanks
Delcare the buttons has private vars, in the init a